# MySQL Subqueries where less than 3 and places more than once

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have two tables i need to query
One called horse which contains the Name and Horse_id
One called entry which contains the Horse_id and the Place. (Place is the where the horse came, eg. 1st, 2nd, 3rd).

I need to use a subquery to display the horse Name and Id of every horse that has won a 1st 2nd or 3rd more than once.

So far i have (i haven't gotten to the "more than once" part yet)

```
SELECT horse_id, name FROM 
(SELECT count(place) AS horse_id, name FROM entry)
WHERE entry.place<3;
```

Although this isn't working. Error is "every derived table must have its own alias". I'm not sure what i'm supposed to name and i'm finding it hard to find examples of this type of query.

I also tried:

```
SELECT horse_id, name FROM horse
WHERE place IN(SELECT horse_id FROM entry WHERE entry.place<3);
```

Not sure where i'm going wrong

Comment: Incidentally, for future reference the derived table error you were getting refers to using a subquery as if it were a table, as you are doing with the select from entry subquery. Such "tables" require an alias which is just a name for the table after the query. For example, in Benson''s answer he has aliased the table cute_little_ponies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize, should have read the question better.. just created the tables on my system this works:

```
select name, horse_id 
FROM horse LEFT JOIN 
(select horse_id, count(horse_id) as c FROM entry where place < 4 group by horse_id) as h 
USING (horse_id) WHERE c > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use a subquery

Comment: @ScottWilson why would you *need* to use a subquery?

Comment: Because this is an assignment that i'm doing. I've been stuck on this question for a couple of hours so i thought i'd put my hand up for help

Comment: @ScottWilson does the assignment actually say "use a subquery to find..." because if so it's a pretty silly assignment. I don't see any reason to impose an artificial restriction on how to retrieve that data...

Comment: Thanks dano, exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest solution would be:

```
SELECT horse_id, name FROM 
(SELECT count(place) AS horse_id, name FROM entry WHERE entry.place<3) as cute_little_ponies;
```

Comment: Same as above, unknown column in field list

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT horse_id, name, SUM(IF(place<=3,1,0)) AS top_3_count
FROM horse
JOIN entry USING (horse_id)
GROUP BY horse_id
HAVING top_3_count > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns only one horse_id with a "top_3_count" of 7. It should return 6 horse_id's with names

Comment: @ScottWilson did you try it with the GROUP BY in there? I forgot it at first and though I edited it in pretty quick it sounds like you caught it before I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Horse_id,Name FROM HORSE
WHERE Horse_id IN 
(SELECT Horse_id FROM ENTRY WHERE Place IN (1,2,3) GROUP BY Horse_id HAVING COUNT(Horse_id)>1);
```